# suggestion only search dialog?

Tags: android, search

I have implemented search dialog with database suggestions follow the android example

but I would like to do couple things differently.

1) When user clicks the result in the suggestion list. I'd like to jump to different activity instead of search activity depends on resource type, in my case, i have category and product.

this is what's in the log, is there a way to override implicit intent?

{ act=com.example.activities.ProductActivity flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.example/.activities.SearchActivity (has extras) }

2) is there way to prevent user from submitting query? i only want the user to choose from what's in the suggestion.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> When user clicks the result in the suggestion list. I'd like to jump to different activity instead of search activity depends on resource type, in my case, i have category and product.

Have the search suggestions route to an invisible activity -- one using `Theme.NoDisplay` and not calling `setContentView()`. In there, make the decision of the right activity to display, call `startActivity()` on it, then call `finish()` to get rid of the invisible activity from the back stack.

> is there way to prevent user from submitting query? i only want the user to choose from what's in the suggestion.

AFAIK, the query is simply to populate the suggestion list, and your search activity cannot be started for anything other than a clicked-upon suggestion. That being said, you cannot change the search system's behavior, so you get whatever they wish to give you.

Comment: #2 is for avoid having a search result page. I think the suggestion list is good enough. Therefore, I would like to disable user click the "go" button or the "magnify glass" icon. Your answering to the #1 solved issue I have with back button by removing searchactivity out of task stack. thank you!!